# Sending data from usercontrol to main page on postback

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I want to create a usercontrol for retrieving and filtering a dataset. The problem I'm having is that the controls to be populated are not in the usercontrol, but on the main page on which the usercontrol exists. The reason for this is that the controls that are to be populated are different on each page.

If I could get some help solving the following simplified problem, I will probably be on my way to solve the bigger problem:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <uc1:uc1 ID="uc1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

What I want to do is set the label on the main page by clicking a button on the usercontrol. Problem I'm having is that the usercontrol postback happens after the main page.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some more code from code behind, I am not understand from where and what you want to send where.

Comment: Well, that's the problem. I'm not sure how to solve it, so there's basically no code. The only code I have is a button event in the user control. But how to set the main page's label from there I do not know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by calling Parent.Page. I also implemented an interface so that I can call different pages' methods from the user control. Not sure if it's a good solution, but it will do:

```
interface IFilter
    {
        void SetLabel(string text);
    }

public partial class uc : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((IFilter)Parent.Page).SetLabel("changed");
        }
    }

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page , IFilter
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {

            }
        }

        public void SetLabel(string text)
        {
            lbl.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a custom event in user control
2. create a property in usercontrol
3. fire the event when the button is clicked & set the property value
4. access the property in the main page in user control's eventhandler